# If a function is called more than million times in a second, print an error

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There is a function in a class if it is called more than one million times in a second we need to print an error. It is basically a design question of what approach we should use.

I am thinking of using a time counter and a count variable. The time counter would reset the count variable whenever its value gets above one million or after every second.

Comment: This is a common usecase for "*throttling*".

Comment: Just don't check the time on each invocation!

Answer (score 3):

If you get 900K calls in 0.1 seconds, and then the counter gets reset by timer, and then you get another 900K calls in 0.1 seconds, then you will have gotten 1.8M calls in a second, but you will fail to print an error.

I would do something like this:

- Every 100K calls, read the clock and store the time in a circular buffer
- Keep 10 times in the buffer, so after at least 1M calls, then whenever you add a new time, it replaces one from 1M calls earlier.  If the difference between these times is less than 1 second, then you should print an error.

In the worst case you could still get up to 1.1M calls in a second without raising an error, but it's probably close enough.  You can use more buffer slots and smaller batches if you need more precision.

Comment: I have a similar solution. Instead of a random size of buffer (like 10 in this answer), it should depend on the desired accuracy of time. If the desired accuracy is of 0.05 secs, make a buffer of 1/0.05 = 20.
This will give better result but could take more memory.

Comment: The number of buffer slots determines the count accuracy, not the time accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think we can have a global variable 'count' for maintaining the frequency of function called which can be updated inside that function itself.
2. Before jumping the gun, we also need to have a global variable 'start_time', initially when function is called for first time we have to set it to the current system time.
3. So if the count reaches 1 Million, then get a timestamp of current system time and check the difference with 'start_time', if the difference is less than 1 sec then print error, else do nothing
4. In either of the cases, we would now reset the 'count' and 'start_time' to current system time and 1